# How to iterate over a JSON object in chunks of 3?

Tags: javascript

So i have a json object that is being served by nodejs.

I'm wanting to make articles in rows of 3, then div's in rows of 3 below the articles (that contain the information for the articles.

```
for (var infoset in jsonObj){
    createArtRow(jsonObj[infoset][info]);

    createDivRow(jsonObj[infoset][info]);
    
    // creates an article, then a div one at a time
}
```

I'm having issues, because i'm unsure how to join the for loop iterating over the object (only 3 at a time).

```
for (var infoset in jsonObj){
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {
        createArtRow(jsonObj[infoset][info]);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
        createDivRow(jsonObj[infoset][info]);
    }     
}
// ideally creates 3 articles, then 3 divs at a time.
```

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Could you add slightly more detail? Maybe with an example jsonObj and an explanation of what article/divs you expect to see?

Comment: Which is your array? It seems variable **i** is not used in the iteration. In other words, if you have an array,  consider using  Lodash's **chunk** function to create an array with groups of 3 elements:
https://lodash.com/docs/#chunk
and then you would iterate the array of groups.

Comment: Sorry, i have been a little vague, i'll see what i can add without making it overly complicated.

Comment: Do you want them «nested», is the correct term. Please add an example output html for fellow helpers. You might have to edit your title to reflect the actual question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop that increments by 3 instead of 1.

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i += 3) {
    // here you can use jsonObj[i], jsonObj[i+1], and jsonObj[i+2] to create a row
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use modulus funcion, which i think is a cleaner more readable approach:

```
let i =0
for (var infoset in jsonObj){ 
  If (i % 3 == 0 ){
   createArtRow(jsonObj[infoset][info]); 
  }
   createDivRow(jsonObj[infoset][info]); 
   i++;
}
```

Modulus (%) function works by deviding 'i' by the number after the % sign.
If the remainder is 0 (so exactly dividable by 3), it will be true and execute the code.